# ANSI sequence to change terminal name

Tags: perl, terminal, ansi-escape

I use a bash script (*konsole-name.sh*) to change a terminal name, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo -en "\e]30;$1\a"
```

and I wanted to use the same method from a perl script that I use to check the GPU temperature, so that it updates periodically the window title.

Yet I didnt find a way.
I tried both this:

```
$comm='echo -en "\e]30;T=$t\a"';
`$comm`;
```

and this, using my bash script:

```
$comm="konsole-name.sh T=$t";
`$comm`;
```

there is some way to do it?

Comment: The console escape sequences work by printing text to the terminal. Backticks gobble up the output of the script. Most likely you just want `print "\e]30;$1\a";` from within Perl.

Comment: how stupid not to see it! Thanks that was exectly it

Comment: [Term::Title](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Title) might be of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The console escape sequences work by printing text to the terminal. In your case, the backticks gobble up the output of the script.

Most likely you just want print "\e]30;$1\a"; from within Perl:

```
my $title = "Fancy terminal title";
print "\e]30;${title}\a";
```

Comment: For the record, since this question is highly ranked on google: if using XTerm or Gnome Terminal, the proper escape sequence is `echo -ne "\e]2;$1\a"` instead